# How can I use KnockoutJs to change my language content?

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to use knockoutJs to change dynamically the content of my webpage, but I am having problems doing that. As KnockoutJs's documentation is not one of the strongest, I might need some help with that, please.

Well, I tried to see if the function wasn´t being called, and it is. To see if the languages variables had some problem, they dont't. Probably it has something to do with the fact that im changing an object not a primitive variable.

```
var english = {
        navbar: {
            dropdown1: {
                title: ko.observable("About the event<span class='caret'></span>"),
                menu: {
                    item2: ko.observable("Preview Editions"),
                    item3: ko.observable("Program"),
                    item4: ko.observable("Subscribe"),
                    item5: ko.observable("Testimonials")
                }
            },
            dropdown2: {
                title: ko.observable("Mais sobre o evento<span class='caret'></span>"),
                menu: {

                }
            },
            dropdown3: {
                title: ko.observable("A Organização<span class='caret'></span>"),
                menu: {

                }
            }
        }
    };

    var portuguese = {
        navbar: {
            dropdown1: {
                title: ko.observable("Sobre a EBEC<span class='caret'></span>"),
                menu: {
                    item2: ko.observable("Edições Anteriores"),
                    item3: ko.observable("Programa"),
                    item4: ko.observable("Inscrição"),
                    item5: ko.observable("Testemunhos")
                }
            },
            dropdown2: {
                title: ko.observable("Mais sobre a EBEC<span class='caret'></span>"),
                menu: {
                    item1: ko.observable("FAQ"),
                    item2: ko.observable("Edições Anteriores"),
                    item3: ko.observable("Programa"),
                    item4: ko.observable("Inscrição"),
                    item5: ko.observable("Testemunhos")
                    item6: ko.observable("Edições Anteriores"),

                }
            },
            dropdown3: {
                title: ko.observable("A Organização<span class='caret'></span>"),
                menu: {

                }
            }

        }
    };

    ko.applyBindings({
        language: ko.observable("en"),
        corpo: ko.observable(portuguese),
        muda: function () {
            if(this.language == "pt"){
                this.corpo = english;
                this.language = "en";
            }else{
                this.corpo = portuguese;
                this.language = "pt";
            }
            alert(this.lingua);
            // i putted that here to see if the function was being called and it is
        }
    });
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!--Links meta-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!--Barra de navegacao-->
    <link href="assets/img/logos/roldana-laranja.png" rel="icon" type="imagem/x-icon">
    <title>EBEC Aveiro 2019</title>
    <!--Google Apis-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300">


    <!--Links jquery-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--Links Form-validation-->
  <link href="assets/form-validation/css/formValidation.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="assets/form-validation/js/formValidation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="assets/form-validation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="estrutura.js"></script>


  <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="assets/js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body data-bind="using: corpo">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top division-blue" style="border:none;" data-bind="using: navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img alt="roldana-EBEC" class="nav-logo-1" src="assets/img/logos/roldana-branca.png">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-right hidden-xs">
            <a target="_blank" href="http://bestaveiro.web.ua.pt/">
                <img alt="logo-BEST" class="nav-logo-2" src="assets/img/logos/best-aveiro-white.png">
            </a>
        </div>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav specialButton">
                <li class="dropdown" data-bind="using: dropdown1">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" data-bind="html: title"></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu division-blue" data-bind="using: menu">
                        <li><a href="#ebec">EBEC Aveiro</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#ebecAnt" data-bind="text: item2"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#programa" data-bind="text: item3"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#apply" data-bind="text: item4"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#testemunhos" data-bind="text: item5"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown" data-bind="using: dropdown2">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" data-bind="html: title"></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu division-blue" data-bind="using: menu">
                        <li><a href="#faqs" data-bind="text: item1"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#juri" data-bind="text: item2"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#partners" data-bind="text: item3"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#equipa" data-bind="text: item4"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#parceria" data-bind="text: item5"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contactos" data-bind="text: item6"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown" data-bind="using: dropdown3">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" data-bind="html: title"></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu division-blue" data-bind="using: menu">
                        <li><a href="#best" data-bind="text: item1"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#info" data-bind="text: item2"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-bind="click: $root.muda, text: lingua">EN</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you also please add the html. That would be helpful. Also note that here `item5: ko.observable("Testemunhos")` a comma is missing and here 
`item6: ko.observable("Edições Anteriores"),` the comma is redundant..

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want some part of the document to update *after* calling `applyBindings`, it has to be bound to an `observable`.

You set your observables by calling them with a value.

```
// Do this
this.language("en");

// Instead of
// this.language = "en"; // <- Knockout won't know something's changed!
```

You read them by calling them without a value

```
// Do this 
if (this.language() === "pt") { }

// Instead of 
// if (this.language == "pt") { }
```

For example:

```js
const dicts = {
  "en": { greeting: "Hello" },
  "de": { greeting: "Hallo" },
  "nl": { greeting: "Hoi" },
  "fr": { greeting: "Bonjour" }
};

const App = function() {
  this.languages = Object.keys(dicts);
  this.language = ko.observable("en");

  this.vm = ko.pureComputed(() =>
    dicts[this.language()] || dicts["en"]
  );
};

ko.applyBindings(new App());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
    Select your language:
    <select data-bind="options: languages, value: language"></select>
    </label>
</div>

<div data-bind="with: vm">
  <h1 data-bind="text: greeting"></h1>
</div>
```